# NumPy np.chararray to nd.array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following np.chararray

```
array = np.chararray(shape=(5))
initialize_array(array) 
# Gives out the following array of type S1
# [b'1' b'0' b'1' b'0' b'1']
```

How can I cast this array to a nd array? I wish for an array like

```
[ 1 0 1 0 1 ] # dtype = int
```

Is this possible via some function that I am not aware of? Or should I do it by "hand"?

---

Using **astype** like:

```
new_ndarray = array.astype("int")
```

Raises a ValueError:

> ValueError: Can only create a chararray from string data.

### MCVE

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np

char_array = np.chararray(shape=(5))
char_array[:] = [b'1',b'0',b'1',b'0',b'1']
nd_array = char_array.astype("int")
```

Comment: Apparently `astype` is trying to produce a new `chararray`.  So it can be used with other char dtypes like `S10` or `U1`.  The docs for `chararray` discourage its use, saying that regular arrays with a string dtype is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.chararray(shape=(5))
array[:] = [b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'1']
array_int = np.array(array, dtype=np.int32)
print(array_int)
# [1 0 1 0 1]
```

Comment: And is it possible to revert this procedure? Go from nd.array to chararray?

Comment: @Broxigar It seems that just doing `array_char = np.chararray(array_int.shape); array_char[:] = array_int` works.